# A zero gravitational potential and non zero gravitational field

Tags: electrostatics, newtonian-gravity, potential

Give an example of a situation in which there is a non-zero gravitational field and a zero gravitational potential at the same point?

$$dV=-\vec E\cdot d\vec r.$$

The above equation implies that such a situation is possible.

Comment: How is it related to electrostatics? The centre of an electric dipole would be a perfect example for such a situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gravitational field $\mathbf g$ equals, by definition, negative of the gradient of a correspondonding potential $\Phi$;
\begin{align}
  \mathbf g = -\nabla\Phi.
\end{align}
Therefore, it suffices to produce a gravitational potential $\Phi$ whose value is zero at a point but whose gradient is non-zero at that point.  This is straightforward to do.

Let a vectors $\mathbf x_0$ and $\mathbf c\neq \mathbf 0$ be given, and define
\begin{align}
  \Phi(\mathbf x) = \mathbf c\cdot (\mathbf x - \mathbf x_0)
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}
  \Phi(\mathbf x_0) = 0, \qquad \nabla\Phi(\mathbf x_0) = \mathbf c\neq 0
\end{align}
and this is a valid gravitational field for vanishing charge density since it satisfies Laplace's equation $\nabla^2\Phi = 0$

Comment: To be honest, I didn't get the last line. What is meant by "vanishing charge density"? Looks like something hypothetical.

Comment: OP is saying the same thing... The dot product in the RHS can go zero. But, it's mathematically. Answer in physical feasibility.

Comment: @Shubham For a charge density $\rho$, the gravitational potential satisfies Poisson's equation $\nabla^2\Phi = 4\pi g \rho$.  If $\rho$ vanishes, then this turns into Laplace's equation $\nabla^2\Phi = 0$.  So my last line is simply to note that the potential I defined is physical.

Comment: Is there a way, for e.g. a mass distribution, even if theoretical, to produce such a potential and vanishing charge density?

Comment: @Shubham Yes.  Consider an infinite plane of uniform surface mass density $\sigma$.